# How to best leverage setInterval to poll an API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So i have this endpoint that I'd like to call multiple times until I get my desired response, and I'd like to know if this approach is a valid way to handle it.

so this endpoint, lets call it `/ping` returns an object with the value as follows `{ping: 1}` now I'd like to hit this endpoint a couple more times or until the value of `ping` changes from `1` to `2`. This is my current approach but there's something that does not sit right with me, I'd like to get a second pair of eyes.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const apiCall = async () => {
    try {
      const ping = await axios({
        url: "https://rest.ensembl.org/info/ping?content-type=application/json",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          accept: "Application/json",
          "Content-Type": "Application/json",
        },
      });
      return ping.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return error.response;
    }
  };

  const myIntervalFunc = () => {
    let myCall = async () => await apiCall();
    let retryNum = 0;
    myCall();
    let interval = setInterval(async () => {
      let intervalCall = await myCall();
      if (intervalCall.ping !== 2) {
        retryNum++;
        console.log("INTERVAL DATA ", intervalCall);
      }
      if (retryNum === 6) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 3000);
  };

  return <button onClick={() => myIntervalFunc()}>Make interval call</button>;
}

export default App;
```

As you can see above, when the user presses the button, an API call is made to our `/ping` endpoint and we retry it 7 times before clearing the interval. Is there a more efficient way or this is good enough? Your feedback is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're waiting for a ping to respond before trying again, I'd suggest changing from `setInterval` to `setTimeout`.

This is because `setInterval` will continue to run at an interval unless cleared.

This means that if the request takes longer than expected, it could potentially receive the response after the next interval has started.

Using `setTimeout` will ensure you receive the response before checking again

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const apiCall = async () => {
    try {
      const ping = await axios({
        url: "https://rest.ensembl.org/info/ping?content-type=application/json",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          accept: "Application/json",
          "Content-Type": "Application/json",
        },
      });
      return ping.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return error.response;
    }
  };

  const myIntervalFunc = () => {
    let myCall = async () => await apiCall();
    let retryNum = 0;
    
    // do you need to call this here?
    // it doesn't seem like this would do anything
    myCall();

    // create interval as a named function
    const interval = async () => {
        let intervalCall = await myCall();
        
        // end loop if ping === 2
        if (intervalCall.ping === 2) {
          return;
        }

        retryNum++;
        console.log("INTERVAL DATA ", intervalCall);
        
        // you don't need to change the `===` to `>=`
        // I find this is a `safe` way to handle it
        // in case something else increments retryNum
        // beyond 6 
        if (retryNum >= 6) {
          return;
        }

        // run `interval` again
        setTimeout(interval, 3000);
    };
    
    // call interval
    interval();
  };

  return <button onClick={() => myIntervalFunc()}>Make interval call</button>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is exactly the feedback that I needed, thank you so much. You’re right, setTimeout is the best approach, and good eye on the ```myCall()```it didn’t do anything. This is exactly what I was looking for, I now know the proper difference between setInterval and setTimeout thanks! 